# Why do we consider left Cauchy-Green tensor in isotropic elasticity?

Tags: continuum-mechanics

Isotropic elasticity starts with the assumption that the constitutive equation of stress depends on a response function that is expressed in terms of left Cauchy green tensor.

Why do we do this assumption?

Comment: There are many linear elastic models, which type are you referring to?
This answer could be relevant to some neo-Hook models:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/385057/183357

Answer (score 0):

A general material has an *elastic potential* or *[strain energy density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_energy_density_function)* (SEDF) that depends on the deformation gradient $\mathbf{F}$ and the structural tensor $\mathbf{M}$. The latter depends on the preferred directions at each point of the material, so the scalar SEDF is:

$$W(\mathbf{F},\mathbf{M})$$

for an isotropic material $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{1}$ (identity matrix). For a rotated frame of reference, the deformation gradient is $\mathbf{RF}$ where $\mathbf{R}$ is a rotation matrix. Then frame-indifference requires $W(\mathbf{RF}) = W(\mathbf{F})$. This can be achieved if:

$$W(\mathbf{F}) = \hat{W}(\mathbf{F}^T\mathbf{F})$$

because $(\mathbf{RF})^T\mathbf{RF} = \mathbf{F}^T\mathbf{R}^T\mathbf{R}\mathbf{F} =  \mathbf{F}^T\mathbf{F}$, since rotation matrices are always orthogonal: $\mathbf{R}^T\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{1}$. Then $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{F}^T\mathbf{F}$ is always a frame-indifferent tensor, so:

$$\hat{W}(\mathbf{C}) = \hat{W}(\mathbf{F}^T\mathbf{F}) = W(\mathbf{F})$$